# How to pass a multi-output return to a function?

Tags: matlab

If I have a multi-output code

```
function [a b] = foo() 
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
end
```

Can we pass foo()'s result to another function directly,

```
function test(a)
   a
end

test(foo());
```

It prints only 1.

I am not sure, in test, how we can destruct its argument. It is not an array.
Do we have to do?

```
[x, y] = foo();
test(x, y);
```

Comment: `bar(foo());` should work just fine,

Comment: @Rashid It seems that only the first returned output is passed in bar.

Comment: They both pass. your function is very simple, try something like `a=1:5`, `b=a.^2`.

Comment: @Rashid I updated my question w/ a full test. It prints only the first returned value.

Comment: Your test(a) function only requests 1 input, therefore the second output of foo() is thrown away. Rewrite as

function test(a,b)

and try again

Comment: @SteveHeim That does not work. MATLAB only supplies foo() to the first argument. I use R2016a. Does what you suggested work for other versions?

Comment: @Joe C, nope that was my bad. I was sure it would work and didn't test it, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no other way.

One variation of this is using a cell arrays and comma-separated lists. Example:

```
C = cell(1,2);
[C{:}] = foo();
bar(C{:})
```

you can reuse the above code for any number of input/output arguments, just replace `2` above with the actual number.

```
C = cell(1,n);
[C{:}] = foo();  % equivalent to [C{1},C{2},...,C{n}] = foo()
bar(C{:})        % equivalent to bar(C{1},C{2},...,C{n})
```