# fplot function with several inputs and outputs

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I am using Octave, but to increase the chances of getting an answer, I would try anything coming from Matlab.

I have a function returning several values, as in

```
function [ a, b ] = myfunc( x, y )
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
endfunction;
```

How would I `fplot` b(x,1)? I actually meant to get an expression that plots that directly. As of now, I came to the conclusion that I would have to first extract b, and then plot it. I actually did not write code for that yet, but if it can be avoided, I would glady do so.

What I *could* do is

```
x = 0 : 0.1 : 4;
[ a, b ] = myfunc( x, 1 );
plot( x, b );
```

but I was wondering if `fplot` can do something like this, in one or two lines.

Comment: it sounds similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36098404/97160. If a function returns multiple variables, you have to "receive" them, there is no other way around it. What you can do is ignore the ones you're not interested in, i.e `[~,b] = myfunc(x,y)`. Of course if they occur at the beginning, you can just write `a = myfunc(x,y)` in which case `b` is not received. Better yet, you can modify your function to return a vector or a cell array instead of separate variables, that way you call it in Octave exactly like hbaderts suggested

Comment: @Amro - Indeed, the link you posted seems to apply to my question. I have actually initially written my function to return a vector, but in my specific case I had to change it to return several values. Perhaps I can fix this, although as of now I do not know how to do that, in my specific case (the details do not belong here). I will tinker a little, and if needed I would post a separate question on that. At any rate, it is not clar to me how to combine the answers/comments with `fplot`, which is an important part of the question.

Comment: honestly it's not worth it, just keep the code as you have now in two separate statements. It is simpler and easier to read, it doesn't have to be all in one line! Just use `~` to ignore unwanted outputs.

Comment: @Amro - This question is just a step towards my goal. I want to have contour plots of various components of a vector function, say, V(a,b,q), where V=(v1,v2,...), a and b are my variables (which I would use for contour plots and for 2D plots at fixed values of a or b), and q are parameters. I suspected that `fplot` was the way to go, but perhaps this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Octave's [nthargout](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Multiple-Return-Values.html) to receive a certain return value.
That you can combine with an [anonymous function](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Anonymous-Functions.html) to pass it to `fplot`.

```
fplot(@(x) nthargout(2, @myfunc, x, 1), [0 1])
```

Comment: +1 because I haven't seen `nthargout` before. But just to be clear, looking at the implementation `edit nthargout` you'll see that it's doing what we just described, that is receiving all the output arguments and returning the requested one. Capturing the outputs can either be done with explicit variables `[out1,out2,..,outN] = f()`, or more conveniently using a cell-array with comma separated lists syntax `[out{:}] = f()` so that it works with arbitrary number of outputs.